# Call class using If as rule

Tags: java, android, class, if-statement, android-activity

I'm new on this Android thing and i dont know how to proceed from this point.

I would like to apply a rule to a button, the idea is simple. I got this button and when i press it, it has two options: it should check the code, if it matches then it start one Activity, if not, keep going as usual.

if it is the "same" as the data base, it goes to this new Activity

else it keep rolling the same class as it is.

also i don't know how to proceed with the execution of this class, how to call it in.

I reach to this code, but i got no idea how to proceed from here.

That is my code :

```
public void Send(View view) throws IOException {
    BdLocal bd = new BdLocal(this);

    if (bd.getCodeCompany() == "0A0A0A0A0A0A0A") {     
        Intent intent = new Intent(NewCompanyCodeActivity.this, NewCompCodeSetup.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } else {
        //i dont know how to put the cass SendHug here
        //Object.getClass(SendHug);?  
    }

    class SendHug extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        ...
    }
```

Separated this Activitys and class work fine

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @KevinEsche the Sting comparison is iffy alright, but that's not the core of the question, so probably not a duplicate

Comment: Instantiate a new instance of SendHug using the `new` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `bd.getCodeCompany() == "0A0A0A0A0A0A0A"`

when you compare two `String` objects with the `==` comparator, you aren't comparing their *value* but rather, you are comparing their `Object` equality. Java checks to see if they are literally the same object, at the same memory location.

This will never be true when comparing a `String` literal such as `"0A0A0A0A0A0A0A"`

In order to compare the *value* of these objects you should call the `.equals()` method on the `String`.

Use of `.equals()` looks like `"0A0A0A0A0A0A0A".equals(bd.getCodeCompany())`.

By calling the method on the `String` literal you avoid a potential `NullPointerException` if it is possible for `bd.getCompany()` to return a `null` value.

You can call `sendHug` like: `new SendHug().execute();`

Comment: Applying the knowledge you share with me, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the if condition like this. And call your AsyncTask in else.

```
public void Send(View view) throws IOException {
        BdLocal bd = new BdLocal(this);
String text = bd.getCodeCompany();
        if ( text.equals( "0A0A0A0A0A0A0A")) {     
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewCompanyCodeActivity.this, NewCompCodeSetup.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        } else {
new SendHug().execute();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly the code i need! Thanks! It works!